# further working with the listview data in code-behind in itemtapped-event

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I created a `ListView` from a JSON file. Now I want to pass the data from the tapped `ViewCell` so I can keep going on with my process.

Here's what this function `listViewJson_ItemTapped` should be doing in the end on each item tapped:

- start the camera where the user must take 2 pictures
- the taken pictures will be named like this: `$"{id}-{curDateTime}.jpg"`
- both pictures will be uploaded on a directory of a webservice where the aforementioned JSON file is stored as well

Right now I have no idea how to pass the data from the tapped `ViewCell`. Further I stuck on the second forced photo. So far my code can take 1 photo but the upload throws an unhandled exception (looking to this problem right now from IIS-side).

Here's the XAML code from the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewJson" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" ItemTapped="listViewJson_ItemTapped">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding id}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding fzg_kz}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding timestamp}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

And here is my C# code-behind from `listViewJson_ItemTapped`:

```
private async void listViewJson_ItemTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
                var format = "MM/dd/yyyy_hh:mm:ss";
                String curDateTime = dt.ToString(format);

                var _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Sample",
                    Name = $"{curDateTime}.jpg"
                });

                if (_mediaFile == null)
                    return;

                var image = new Image();
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    return _mediaFile.GetStream();

                });

                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/files";
                var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
            };
        }
```

This problem really gives me a headache because I can't continue my work without this.
I'm new to programming so any advice and references will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Paul

Comment: The problem of the unhandlex exception is probably a bad request or that the picture is too large. You might want to make 2 pictures first and than upload them ( or you could start uploading one in the background.) Just do a for loop of the camera. 2ndly what do you mean with can't acces the data of listview? Do you want for instance the id?

Comment: @JordyDieltjens Hey Jordy, thanks for your reply. I'm currently checking the unhandled exception. Right now I'm organize to real devices so it becomes more "real"...Good idea with the camera loop. I just put this in a new ContentPage so I can apply something like a ProgressBar as well?! With accessing data from the ListView I meant that I need the binded information from the ViewCell for e.g. to generate unique file names for the fotos etc. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly this should be what you want for getting the unique file names:

```
((ObjectType)(e.Item)).Id.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Don't forget to swap the ObjectType by the object that you used to fill up the list.

For the camera twice i'd suggest to just make a simple loop, and indeed you can use a simple progressbar if you'd like.

Any progress on that unhandled exception so far? What I like to do to find it an error like this is write the json in my output debug, copy the json into Postman and than send it. Than u will get a better error than Unhandled

I hope this was clear, gl!

Edit some extra example for the id.

So for instance you got following JSON:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30
}
```

Now if this is in the list and you clicked you need to convert this.
We create the Class Called Person and give this 2 fields ( name and age)
      public class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;

```
    public Person() {

    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use my code that I gave you first, just replace ObjectType with Person.

```
((Person)(e.Item)).Id.ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

How I upload my picture (note this is a dirty version, meaning it still neds some cleaning up of some dirty code that I put for testing reason, it also has the json in your debug window still there, so use that if it doesn't work, the client I use is of type Httpclient like you, I gave it a base address. If anything is not clear don't hesistate to ask

```
public static bool InsertAllFotos(tTodo ttodo, List<Fotos> fotos, List<string> blob)
        {
            //var test2 = blob[0].blob_data.Bytes;
            List<tSyndFoto> tFotos = new List<tSyndFoto>();
            foreach(var foto in fotos)
            {
                tSyndFoto tFoto = new tSyndFoto();
                tFoto.id_synd_dossier = ttodo.id_gebouw;
                tFoto.omschrijving = foto.Omschrijving;
                tFoto.id_todo = ttodo.id_todo;
                tFotos.Add(tFoto);
            }

            JObject json = new JObject();

            json.Add("fotos", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tFotos));

            //tBlob tmpBlob = new tBlob();
            //tmpBlob.blob_data = new Binary();
            //tmpBlob.blob_data.Bytes = new byte[0];
            // tmpBlob.blob_data.Bytes =  blob[0].blob_data.Bytes;
            //var lijst = new List<tBlob>();
            //lijst.Add(tmpBlob);
            json.Add("blobs", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blob));
            //json.Add("blobs", null);
            //string test = json.ToString();

            //var jon2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(blob[0].blob_data.Bytes.ToString());
            var test = json.ToString();
           test =  test.Replace("\"[", "[");
           test =  test.Replace("]\"", "]");
           // test = test.Replace("\\n", "");
            test = test.Replace("\\", "");

            Debug.WriteLine(test);
            var content = new StringContent(test, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


            var resp = client.PostAsync("InsertFotos", content);


            if (resp.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var repStr = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                JObject jo = JObject.Parse(repStr.Result.ToString());
                return jo.SelectToken("InsertFotosResult", false).ToObject<bool>();



            }

            return false;
        }
```

Here is the JSON I get from this ( blobs is my picture, I cutted away some data because it's too large:

```
    {
  "fotos": [{"id_synd_foto":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","id_blob":null,"id_synd_dossier":"xxx","web_image":null,"uploaded":null,"omschrijving":null,"datum":null,"id_todo":"xx","id_synd_eigenaarsnet_melding":null,"id_eigenaar":null,"id_synd_kavel":null,"bijlage_melding":null}],
  "blobs": ["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"]
}
```

Comment: Hello Jordy, you misunderstood me with the `Id`. The `Id` is coming from my JSON file which I parsed into my `x:Name="listViewJson"` (look at the XAML code). And now I want to access the `Id` from the tapped ViewCell in this `ListView`, you know what I mean? I'm currently not working very much on this code because of other stuff. I downloaded Postman just now and trying to do what you told me. But why you mentioned the JSON? I want to upload the taken picture? Thanks for your reply again. Paul

Comment: You should be able to get the id with my answer since you put that json inside a list. What you need to do extra now is create a class with the fields from the json file so you can convert the listviewitem into that object. ( if it's not clear i'll give you an example ). For the JSON part uploading of the picture I assumed you were using json to upload the picture, that's how I did it. How do you currently try uploading it ?

Comment: An example would be really appreciated. Currently I am trying to upload the image with the HttpClient. I already have created the classes with its properties. And I think your Code with that you are uploading your pictures would be really helpful as well. Thank you Jordy!

Comment: I've added some of my code, sorry for the comment lines between the code, had no time yet to clean It up

Comment: Hey Jordy, thanks for your reply. You were right with your code to access the id-value. It worked after I changed the `EventArgs` to `ItemTappedEventsArgs`. I've read your upload code but right now I'm not unterstanding this. Maybe the day was too lang so far. I'm looking tomorrow or in the beginning of next week and will let you know! Thank you so much so far! You are really helpful!

Comment: I will be their tommorow to help you too, my code isn't 100% right, i made it quickly because of a deadline and haven't had a chance to tweak it yet. If you find me helpfull an upvote of answer is always appreciated ;). And when all your problems are solved don't forget to mark me as answer :D

Comment: I won't forget you. You are my hero.

Comment: Hey Jordy. I can't follow your code for uploading a recently taken picture through JSON. Where do you refenrece to the local file on the device which supposed to be uploaded? Is it easier to write code for uploading 1 image and then repeate the method with the 2nd picture? Because in your code you are creating a List don't you? Can you specify and clean the code for one single picture and I will adapt this to my variables? Paul

Comment: I convert the local file(=picture) to an encoded base64 string. In my example the list called blobs is the one with the base64 string. It's better to upload 1 picture at a time. When I tried multiple pictures at once I was having issue with my server that I was going over the limit. For serializing it doesn't matter that it's a list or not, just depends how it is on the server side. So changing my code is not really needed, you just swap list<string> to string for you code. My foto object I keep the name and date of the pic

Comment: And what did you do on the server side to get the picture? Currently I just have a Webserver role and want to store it in a normal directory.

Comment: I'll explain what I used it for. So I got an app where people make pictures of problems with their houses. Theses pictures get requested from the server which store these pictures in a mysqlbase utilizing base64 strings ( which is kinda best practise to keep them that way ) When I want to show these pictures I convert the string to bytes which I than put in a memorystream. ( than u got the picture their source ). I hope this made it a bit clear

Comment: Did you succed @paulvoelker

Comment: I didnt. I was not able to work further on my app so far. I have not forget you.

Comment: in this thread i succeded to pass the properties in my codebehind thanks to you. i closed this thread, but openend [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954842/upload-recently-taken-image-from-android-ios-crossplatform-xamarin-forms-with) one if you dont mind to look over this too.