# Upload recently taken Image from Android/iOS (Crossplatform xamarin.forms) with MediaPlugin on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

currently I'm stuck on uploading the images which I took within my app on my own asp.net webserver. I used the Media.Plugin from James Montemagno. Taking the image works fine.

The problem: I'm getting a unhandled exception when uploading the image.

In my solution I created a new WebApplication as referenced in the youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVvJX4CoLUY&t=1837s)! I did almost everything like him.

Here is my WebApplication Code:

```
public async Task<string> Post()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                    {
                        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                        var fileName = "test.png";
                            // postedFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + fileName);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return exception.Message;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here is my code for taken the images and uploading it:

```
 private async void listViewJson_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
                    var format = "MM/dd/yyyy_hh:mm:ss";
                    String curDateTime = dt.ToString(format);
                    var process_fullname = ((Process)(e.Item)).id.ToString() + "-" + curDateTime;

                    var _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "Sample",
                        Name = $"{process_fullname}.jpg",
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
                        SaveToAlbum = true
                    });

                    if (_mediaFile == null)
                        return;

                    var image = new Image();
                    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                    {
                        return _mediaFile.GetStream();
                    });

                    await DisplayAlert("ok", _mediaFile.AlbumPath, "ok");

                    try
                    {
                        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                        content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), 
                            "\"file\"", 
                            $"\"{_mediaFile.AlbumPath}\"");
                        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://localhost:53188/";
                        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
                        var remotePath = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        throw exception;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Paul

Comment: which exception do you get, and where (in App or on web server, call stack)?

Comment: i cant tell in specific because when i am debugging the webapp i cant debug the app for further information. but the app stops working when it comes to upload

Comment: it will be worth establishing a properly debuggable setup first. is the app running in an emulator? otherwise you would not be able to map localhost:53188 like this. and is it mapped, and accessible (check in device/emulator's browser!) the exception handler (catch bock with throw inside) is useless as it just masks the actual exception. Use the catch for debug output or a messagebox.

Comment: hey, i did what you told me. i am getting the error: `an error occured while sending the request`

Comment: still not enough. so much can go wrong with an http POST: url resolution, authorization, ... could you output the whole `exception.ToString()` so we maybe get a useful error code, and the exception call stack? If the request reaches the web server, there should also be a corresponding entry in the IIS log file, where the last few columns contain the http error codes.

Comment: hey, now i used the `ToString()` and i get a `System.Net.Http-HttprequestException: An Error occured while sending the request --> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) --> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.Endpoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] [...more text...]`. tell me if you need the whole text (its on my device and i need to tip it into my computer.

Comment: don't use localhost, use the IP or FQDN of the server.  Also be sure IIS is setup to allow remote connections.

Comment: we still don't know if you're emulating, or run on an actual device. the "connection refused" error is still not very specific, but it tells us that "localhost:53188" cannot be reached. open up a browser on the device and make sure you can reach the URL you want to POST to. once this works, repeat the POST request with the working URL. check the IIS log file to see if the request is blocked before or after it reaches IIS pipeline.

Comment: i am  running the app on a physical device (currently android). when i am sending a POST with the tool "postman" i am getting this error: `<h2>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>
                    <h3>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.</h3>` i am not imported my webapplication yet on my iis (working on it). but basically this should be running anyway besides of getting the file dont it?

Comment: now i've added a new handler on my iis site that allows POST. nevertheless im getting another error: now its `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.`. i gave read/write permission to the physical directory and `anonymus authentication` is enabled...step by step...